# Technicality: convergent sequence is preserved by continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm looking at the proof of a basic result in Maxwell Rosenlicht's analysis book:

> Let $(E,d)$, $(E',d')$ be metric spaces. Let $f: E \to E'$ be a function. Then
>   if, for every sequence of points $p_1, p_2, \ldots $ in $E$ such that
>   $p_n \to p$ we also have $f(p_n) \to f(p)$, then $f$ is continuous at $p$.

The proof starts out straightforward enough:

> Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $p$. Then there exists some $\epsilon>0$
>   such that for no $\delta>0$ is it true that whenever $x \in E$ and
>   $d(x,p)<\delta$ then necessarily $d'(f(x), f(p))<\epsilon$. Then for any
>   $n=1,2,\ldots$ we can find a point $p_n \in E$ such that $d(p_n, p) < 1/n$ and $d'(f(p_n), f(p)) \geq \epsilon$...

My question is: why is it possible at all to find these points in $(p_n)$ which satisfy this?

My sense is that if such a sequence $p_n \to p$ doesn't exist in $E$, then $f$ is automatically continuous at $p$ (maybe this is false? I should think it over more). But this proof (as presented) seems to suggest that such a sequence always exists. Or is the sequence some sort of trivial sequence that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $d(x, p) < \delta \Rightarrow d'(f(x), f(p)) < \varepsilon$ is false, there must be some $x \in E$ with $d(x, p) < \delta$ and $d'(f(x), f(p)) \geq \varepsilon$.

In particular, if we let $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$, there is $p_n \in E$ (here $p_n$ plays the role of $x$) with $d(p_n, p) < \frac{1}{n}$ and $d'(f(p_n), f(p)) \geq \varepsilon$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had a hunch that's what was happening. So if there were not some point satisfying that, then the statement would be vacuously true. In other words, if those points did not exist, then the function would be "trivially" continuous?

Comment: @gogurt: Correct.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence that converges to $p$ always exists, here is one:
$$p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,\dots$$

If $E$ contains at least one point that is not $p$, say $q$, then another sequence that converges to $p$ is $$q,q,q,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,\dots.$$

There actually exist such metrics that the only sequences that converge to $p$ are the sequences for which there exists an $n$ such that $p_i=p$ for all $i>N$. The metric that demands this the trivial metric $d(x,y)=\delta_{xy}$ which equals $1$ if $x\neq y$ and $0$ otherwise (this is indeed a metric!)

In the trivial metric, it is then easy to see that every function is continuous, since every sequence that converges to $p$ is constant from some point on, meaning $f(p_i)$ is also constant from some point on.

---

The main point is that the proof only says something about all sequences that converge to $p$. It does not *say* that these sequences exist.